# Selected arears Clear cell contents

Tags: excel

I use Yes/No Button to clear content in the selected area. The first click removes the Selected Area data correctly, and every time you click without data in the Selected Area, the data below the Selected Area is removed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I guess those buttons are linked to any code? Did you check it out?

Comment: Could you post the code behind the buttons please - you can edit your question using the Edit button just below the tags.